# Build a Tree based on a dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, recursion, tree

I am trying to build a Tree based on data to be found in a dictionary. I know that this could be achieved using recursion, but I am facing troubles solving this problem.
The goal would be to construct a Tree in the form of:

```
class Tree():
def __init__(self, data) -> None:
    self.data = data
    self.children = []
def addChildren(self, child):
    self.children.append(child)
```

The following dictionary should be "parsed" and represented by a Tree.

```
{
   "PaymentCoverageRequestResource":{
      "required":[
         "accountId",
         "paymentCoverageRequestId"
      ],
      "type":"object",
      "properties":{
         "paymentCoverageRequestId":{
            "maxLength":35,
            "type":"string",
            "description":"Identification of the payment Coverage Request"
         },
         "payee":{
            "maxLength":70,
            "type":"string",
            "description":"The merchant where the card is accepted as information to the PSU."
         },
         "instructedAmount":{
            "type":"object",
            "properties":{
               "amount":{
                  "maxLength":70,
                  "type":"string",
                  "description":"The merchant where the card is accepted as information to the PSU."
               },
               "currency":{
                  "maxLength":3,
                  "type":"string",
                  "description":"The merchant where the card is accepted as information to the PSU."
               }
            }
         },
         "accountId":{
            "$ref":"another reference"
         }
      },
      "description":"Payment coverage request structure.\nThe request must rely either on a cash account or a payment card.\nThe [instructedAmount] property is the payment account on wihich the request is processed. This amount must be positive.\nAmounts must always be set as positive values.\n",
      "example":"{\n  \"paymentCoverageRequestId\" : \"MyCoverage123456\",\n  \"instructedAmount\" : {\n    \"amount\" : 12345.0,\n    \"currency\" : \"EUR\"\n  },\n  \"accountId\" : {\n    \"iban\" : \"YY13RDHN98392489481620896668799742\"\n  }\n}",
      "x-definition-type":"Resources"
   }
}
```

A node is considered to be a parent-node, if and only if it contains the key-value pair

> "type":"object"

Its children are all the key-value pairs found in "properties".

I tried to solve this problem using the following code, but it am lacking some experience.

```
def parse_json(requestBody : dict):
    def parse_json_rec(tree : Tree, requestBody : dict):
        #something ?
        if len(requestBody) == 0:
            return tree
        
        (k, v), = requestBody.items()
        requestBody.pop(k)
        print(k)
        
        if v['type'] == 'object': # OR ARRAY
            parent_node = Tree(k)
            print(v)
            return parse_json_rec(tree.addChildren(parse_json_rec(parent_node, v), requestBody))
        else:
            leaf_node = Tree(k)
            tree.addChildren(leaf_node)
            return parse_json_rec(tree, requestBody)
        pass
    root = Tree("root")
    return parse_json_rec(root, requestBody)
```

The result I would like to achieve is a Tree containing multiple nodes as represented here:

```
PaymentCoverageRequestResource
     paymentCoverageRequestId
     payee
     instructedAmount
          amount
          currency
     accountId
```

Comment: Hi. Just a quick note: I think it would be better to have either `def addChild(self, child): self.children.append(child)` or `def addChildren(self, children): self.children.extend(children)`, or both, but not `def addChildren(self, child)` which says "children" but adds a single child.

Comment: I also suggest adding a `children` optional parameter to `__init__`: `def __init__(self, data, children=None): if children is None: children = []; self.data = data; self.children = children`. This way you can build trees easily by just writing `Tree('root', [Tree('left subtree', [...]), Tree('right subtree', [...])])`

Comment: Also it should probably be either `if v.get('type') == 'object'` or `if 'type' in v and v['type'] == 'object'` instead of just `if v['type'] == 'object'`, to avoid crashing when there is no `'type'` entry in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues I see that might be causing you trouble are:

1. The weird pattern trying to pop items from the input, and doing recursion on the same-level when there are multiple leaves.

```
>>> d = {'a':1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> (k,v), = d.items()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

Consider instead, just making a loop over the properties instead of doing recursion on the same level, I think it'd be easier to understand.

```
def parse_tree(node):
  for k,v in node.items():
    if is leaf: ...
    if is node: ... tree.addChild(k, parse_tree(v))
```

2. What does tree.addChildren return, and is that the right thing to pass to parse_json_rec?

Answer (score 0):

I reasonably created a package [AbstractTree](https://pypi.org/project/abstracttree) which can solve this:

```py
import abstracttree
from abstracttree import print_tree


class Tree(abstracttree.DownTree):
    def __init__(self, name, data):
        self.name = name
        self.data = data

    @property
    def children(self):
        if self.data.get("type") == "object":
            return [Tree(k, v) for k, v in self.data["properties"].items()]
        else:
            return ()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


[item] = data.items()
tree = Tree(*item)
print_tree(tree)
```

The output looks like this:

```
PaymentCoverageRequestResource
├─ paymentCoverageRequestId
├─ payee
├─ instructedAmount
│  ├─ amount
│  └─ currency
└─ accountId
```